# Dynamically register listeners in swing

Tags: java, swing, combobox, listener, classcastexception

I have created UI that populates components dynamically. 
The UI is like table, which has X number of rows, but having 4 components [1 JLable, 3 JComboboxes] in each row. I want to register listeners for all comboboxes, to fetch the    **selectedItem()** from comboboxes and use it for further reference. But, I am not able to do it using my existing code.
The code is below.

```
    for(int i=0; i< list.size(); i++) {
        final int j = i;

        cb1[i] = new JCombobx();
        masterPanel[i].add(cb1[i]);

        cb2[i] = new JCombobx();
        masterPanel[i].add(cb2[i]);

        cb3[i] = new JCombobx();
        masterPanel[i].add(cb3[i]);

            cb1[j].addItem("Select Value");
            for (OtherObject l : List) {
                cb1[j].addItem(l);
            }

        cb1[j].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                selectedValue = (SomeObject) cb1[j].getSelectedItem();
            }
        }); 
    }
```

I  am getting this exception :

```
    java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to SomeObject
```

In this, combobox[cb2] will be populated according to the value selected from cb1 and eventually third combobox will be populated according to the value selected from cb2.
What's wrong in it?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) See [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/418556) Note that compilation errors and stack traces are things that most programmers face regularly, it is advisable to do some research into the cause & fixing them before asking for help on Stack Overflow. I see no evidence that you have done that in this instance.

Answer (score 2):

The exception is very clear: obviously, you put **strings** into your first combo box object (in the code that you aren't showing here).

A string object can **never** be casted to (SomeObject) class.

So, there are two ways to fix that:

1. You look into the code that actually adds the values to your first combo box. That code should be adding instances of SomeObject, if you want to use SomeObject
2. Or, if it is correct that your first box works with strings; then you have to change your code that currently tries to cast the string returned by getSelectedItem() ... to not cast!

Comment: *"The code for that is here"* Where is the MCVE that allows us to run it & see an example of the problem?

Comment: Trust us: if we think that we dont understand your question because code is missing, then **we dont understand your question because code is missing**. Don't come back to us with "the code is here"!

Comment: Plus: exception messages **do not lie**. But humans often do **err**. It is as I said: the exception tells you exactly that you put **Strings** in your combobox. If you dont believe that ... that wont change a bit in the real nature of your problem.

Comment: Sorry for previous comments... May it be due to 1D array?

Comment: Stop speculating. POST YOUR CODE. We do **not** have a magic crystal ball that would tell us what is going on in your code. And as said: I already gave you a very clear thing to start looking at. So, you should find your way from that point; or you POST YOUR CODE. Anything else is a waste of your time, and ours.